# Capturing a PHP var inside a foreach loop in javascript and using it in an other PHP page.

Tags: javascript, php

I got the following php `foreach` loop in the **A page** of my web appliation. And i want to use the `$watson` variable which is inside this loop in an other php **B page**. What i did is used this variable as a value in an extra  input button:`<input type="button"/ value="<?php echo $watson; ?>`,so to be able to capture this var in javascript like you see below.

```
<tbody>
    <?php 
        foreach($records as $r) {
            $watson = $r->case_reference;
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo  escape($r->user); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo  escape($r->customer); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo  escape($r->vessel); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo  escape($r->country); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo  escape($r->port); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo  escape($r->eta); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo  escape($r->service_station); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo  escape($r->type_of_service); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo  escape($r->case_reference); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo  escape($r->status); ?></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="<?php echo $watson; ?>" onclick="popEdit(this.value);" /></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
</tbody>
```

The code for the `onclick="popEdit(this.value);"`function which pops up the **B page** mentioned above is :

```
function popEdit(str) {
    window.open("example.php?watson="+str, "pop_edit_jobs",
                 "width=400,height=350,scrollbars=no,left=460,top=400")
}
```

And the php **B page** code starts as `$ref_num = $_GET['watson'];`  so i can use the variable.

My problem is that i dont want the input/button in the **A page** to show the variable on it instead i want it to just show the word **EDIT**.But to do that i ll have to change its value and  then i wont be able to  capture this `$watson` var in javascript.

Any suggestions regarding how to achieve the above effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td><input type="button" value="EDIT" onclick="popEdit('<?php echo $watson; ?>');" /></td>
```

should achieve the desired effect.

Comment: This really works like a charm. I am so stupid for not thinking that earlier,guess lack of experience counts.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a form around your entire table, then use submit buttons:

```
<input type="submit" name="watson" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($watson); ?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Do you mean wrapping the whole table in the A page in a form which will post at the B page via "GET" method and puting `$watson=$_GET['watson'];` ? This way i can get the `$watson` var without javascript??